# How to get model index children in QSortFilterProxyModel of QFileSystemModel?

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a file system folder with wollowing structure on a Hard disk:

[image]

So, I want to see the the folliwing structure in my QTreeView:

[image]

I try to use QSortFilterProxy model to do that.
My strategy:

1. identify 'Folder_1' item in filterAcceptsRow and decline insertion of 'Folder_1' and its children
2. recursively get children of 'Folder_1' (because it can has another folders)
3. insert children instead of 'Folder_1'

So, I stuck on step 2.
Is my strategy right?
How to get children of parent item in filterAcceptsRow ?
Do I have to use another method to do that?
Where (instance and method) I should do children insertion (step 3)?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel


class MyFilterModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFilterModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):

        index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        print('data =', index.data())
        if index.data() == 'Folder_1':
            child_index = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow+1, 0, sourceParent)
            print(child_index.data())

        rowCount = self.sourceModel().rowCount(index)

        accepted = QSortFilterProxyModel.filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow,
                                                          sourceParent)

        if rowCount > 0 and not accepted:
            for row in range(rowCount):
                if self.filterAcceptsRow(row, index):
                    return True

        return accepted


class Myview(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self._root_path = r"C:\Users\Dmitriy.Kubarev\Documents\TEST_FILE_SYSTEM"

        model = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel()
        sourceIndex = model.setRootPath(self._root_path)

        proxy_model = MyFilterModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)

        view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        view.setModel(proxy_model)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('ok')

        main_layout.addWidget(button)
        main_layout.addWidget(view)
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)

        proxyIndex = proxy_model.mapFromSource(sourceIndex)
        view.setRootIndex(proxyIndex)

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myview = Myview()
    myview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why do you delete your previous post and create a new one with the same question? That is really annoying since you erase the effort that users put in to leave you comments.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried to explain more and ask another questions, but regarding the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/ noticed me I post the same question and sugested me to delete previous

Comment: What you should do is never publish a new post unnecessarily. Instead you should edit your previous post because if you want more attention then with each edition your post is relaunched to the queue of active questions

Comment: Ok, a next time I will to so, sorry. Thank you